# UK visitor visa checklist

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I went to my biometric appointment today and the officer there said they do not sign/check the document checklist. On the checklist there are instructions to sign at the time of the appointment. I plan to mail in my application to New York.

Is that checklist required to be submitted? Who is supposed to sign and check it (the official columns).

Comment: Did you ask them to explain? My understanding is that the applicant must sign and submit the checklist as confirmation that they understand the application process and that documents submitted are genuine. I surmise that the officer at your appointment did not sign it as the ‘Submission Officer’, because they were not acting in that capacity since you are mailing your application papers to New York yourself.

Answer (score 1):

When I was applying for UK visa via TLScontact center in Ireland (Dublin) in 2017, I brought the checklist with me, however, it was not taken by the officer.

TLScontact printed their own checklist though, which I had to sign. And then I was required to bring this checklist with me when the passport was ready for collection. This TLScontact checklist is mentioned in their [FAQ: How can I collect my passport?](https://uk.tlscontact.com/ie/DUB/page.php?pid=faq#How%20can%20I%20collect%20my%20passport?) as well.